# Passenger Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to Unix socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I just moved my rails app to a new machine.  I'm using apache 2.2.3 and passenger 3.0.11.  After initial load of the databases, I'm intermittently seeing an error that says the rails app failed to start.  Here's what I see in my apache error log:

```
[Sun Mar 18 04:02:13 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[ pid=10788 thr=47366521234240 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:860 time=2012-03-18 08:51:10.215 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to Unix socket '/tmp/passenger.1.0.13044/generation-0/socket': No such file or directory (2)
Backtrace:
 in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client* Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::connect(const std::string&, const std::string&, const Passenger::StaticString&)' (Client.h:438)
 in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client* Hooks::getApplicationPool()' (Hooks.cpp:266)
 in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:292)
 in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:561)
```

I've done some googling but I can only seem to find the passenger guy saying to upgrade passenger to version 3, but I'm already on version 3.  I also saw somebody saying to change the logrotate script to restart apache rather than reload, which did nothing for me.  Does anybody have any ideas?  Here's my apache conf for passenger.  I'm using an rvm version of ruby enterprise and passenger installed as a gem:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/ruby
```

I've also tried adding rails spawn method as conservative and adding a max pool size, with the same results.  Not sure where to turn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have SELinux enabled? Run `cat /selinux/enforce` to find out. If it prints `1`, try disabling SELinux with `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce` to see if that solves the problem . If that fixes the problem, you can choose to try to work around it (e.g. by setting the `PassengerTempDir` setting. Search for SELinux in the [Passenger user guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html)) or leave it turned off permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I checked and my /selinux directory is empty and my /etc/selinux/config file shows SELINUX=disabled.  As an additional note I'm on centos 5.7

Comment: Does your /etc/logrotate.d/httpd have a postrotate command of `/sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true` ? Otherwise, you might want to try recompiling passenger -- perhaps some underlying libraries changed.

Comment: It has that same command in it.  One post I read about this same error message said that changing it from reload to restart fixed the problem for him, but didn't work for me.  I see the same issue both with restart and reload.

Comment: I'm running Passenger 3.0.11 on CentOS as well, and that's the line I use. Have you tried installing REE/Passenger without rvm?

Comment: I installed passenger as a standalone and pointed apache to its module.  I thought it was magically working, but after a few hours I was seeing the error again.  It seems to be that the master apache process id changes but passenger doesn't keep up, which leads me to believe that an apache restart is causing the problem.  I just don't understand where it's coming from.  I could be way off base here, though.  I've dumped passenger 3.0.11 and went down to 3.0.0 which is what the old machine is running.  However, I doubt this is going to help.  I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong.  The apache process ID remains the same.  However, something wipes out every file in the directory where the socket should be except for directories

Comment: You could have some app that aggressively deletes items in /tmp. Set PassengerTempDir directive to another directory so that Passenger doesn't get trampled on.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it seems to be stable.  Now if I could just figure out who the culprit is... it's not tmpwatch

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem. I tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

**As last solution you always can "really" restart everything:**

```
sudo killall httpd # <---------
sudo service httpd status
httpd is stopped
sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```